# Order a NSURL array

Tags: swift, sorting, nsurl

I'm loading a lot of image paths into a NSURL. 
The images are in a folder ordered from 1.PNG, 2.PNG, 3.PNG to 1500.PNG.
 When I trie to load them:

```
let imagePath = path + "/images"
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
        print(url)
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let properties = [NSURLLocalizedLabelKey,
                          NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey]

        do {
            imageURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: properties, options:NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            print(error1.description)
        }
```

The imageURLs array gets filled with:

> imageURLs[0] = ...\0.PNG
>    imageURLs[1] =  ...\1.PNG
>     imageURLs[2] = ...\100.PNG 
>     imageURLs[3] = ...\1000.PNG

and not in the numeric order! 
Can someone help to sort the imageURLs or while i load the image paths on it or after they are loaded?

Comment: You'll have to use the `sort` function with a custom closure which specifies how any given pair of elements compares in the sort. This closure would need to parse out the numbers from the given `NSURL`s to compare them.

Comment: Just name your images 0001.png, 0002.png, ... it should work better without complex programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to sort the files by the number you have to parse first the path to achieve it, so let's suppose we have the following array of `NSURL` objects:

```
var urls = [NSURL(string: "file:///path/to/user/folder/2.PNG")!, NSURL(string: "file:///path/to/user/folder/100.PNG")!, NSURL(string: "file:///path/to/user/folder/101.PNG")!, NSURL(string: "file:///path/to/user/folder/1.PNG")! ]
```

We can use the [`pathComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/pathComponents) property to extract an array with all the components in the path for a `NSURL` (e.g `["/", "path", "to", "user", "folder", "2.PNG"]`).

If we see we can order the files by the last element in the array that is the filename removing the extension and the dot(`"."`), in this case the number. Let's see how to do it in the following code:

```
urls.sortInPlace {

   // number of elements in each array
   let c1 = $0.pathComponents!.count - 1
   let c2 = $1.pathComponents!.count - 1

   // the filename of each file
   var v1 = $0.pathComponents![c1].componentsSeparatedByString(".")
   var v2 = $1.pathComponents![c2].componentsSeparatedByString(".")

   return Int(v1[0]) < Int(v2[0])
}
```

In the above code we use the function `sortInPlace` to avoid create another array with the elements sorted, but can you use `sort` instead if you want. The another important point in the code is the line `return Int(v1[0]) < Int(v2[0])`, in this line we have to convert the number in the string to a real number, because if we compare the two strings `"2"` and `"100"` the second one is less than greater than because the string are compared lexicographically.

So the the array `urls` should be like the following one:

```
[file:///path/to/user/folder/1.PNG, file:///path/to/user/folder/2.PNG, file:///path/to/user/folder/100.PNG, file:///path/to/user/folder/101.PNG]
```

> **EDIT:**

The two functions `pathComponents` and `componentsSeparatedByString` increase the space complexity of the `sortInPlace` algorithm, if you can asure that the path for the files always will be the same except it's filename that should be a number you can use instead this code:

```
urls.sortInPlace { $0.absoluteString.compare(
                   $1.absoluteString, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Works fine, except that it takes almost one minute to order, blocking the app for that time.  @Victor

Comment: @Danny182 How much items do you have in the folder, the sort algorithm not should be take much time, are you sure it's the sort algorithm?

Comment: 1500 paths. Yes it's that, if I comment the sort algorithm everything is ok. I'm checking the CPU usage from Xcode @Victor

Comment: @Danny182 See my updated answer maybe it can improve the time

Comment: yes! now it's perfect. A little slow on 4S but good on other devices

Comment: Thanks. what is `sortInPlace`. some kind of function ?

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit late, anyway this worked for me in **Swift 5**

```
imageURLs.sort {
        ($0.pathComponents.last?.components(separatedBy: ".").first)! < ($1.pathComponents.last?.components(separatedBy: ".").first)!
    }
```

This takes path components from url(separated by /), then take the last part and take components of it ( separated by . ). Then take first part and compare with the other urls similarly.

Complexity: O(n log n), where n is the length of the collection[ as per Apple doc]