# How to increment String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, sorting, character

I need to save files in an alphabetical order. 
Now my code is saving files in numeric order

> 1.png
>   2.png
>   3.png
>  ...

The problem is when i read this files again I read this files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819395/order-a-nsurl-array)

So I was thinking of changing the code and to save the files not in a numeric order but in an **alphabetical order** as:

> a.png
>  b.png
>  c.png
>  ...
>  z.png
>  aa.png
>  ab.png
>  ...

But in Swift it's difficult to increment even *Character* type.
How can I start from:

```
var s: String = "a"
```

and increment *s* in that way?

Comment: So you want to map those numerical names to the ones containing letters? What does that have to do with incrementing?

Comment: no. That's the way that i save the files now. I was thinking of saving the files in the alphabetical order instead of the numeric as it is now. I'll try to explain better.

Comment: `I was thinking of saving the files in the alphabetical order instead of the numeric as it is now.` ...So you want to map those numerical names to the ones containing letters.

Comment: @Danny182 : Have you take a look over my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Paste this code in the playground and check result. `n` numbers supported means you can enter any high number such as 99999999999999 enjoy!
>
> you can uncomment `for loop` code to check code is working fine or not
>   but don't forget to assign a lesser value to `counter` variable otherwise Xcode will freeze.

```
var fileName:String = ""
var counter = 0.0
var alphabets = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
let totalAlphaBets = Double(alphabets.count)
let numFiles = 9999


func getCharacter(counter c:Double) -> String {

    var chars:String
    var divisionResult = Int(c / totalAlphaBets)
    let modResult = Int(c.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: totalAlphaBets))

    chars = getCharFromArr(index: modResult)

    if(divisionResult != 0){

        divisionResult -= 1

        if(divisionResult > alphabets.count-1){
            chars = getCharacter(counter: Double(divisionResult)) + chars
        }else{
            chars = getCharFromArr(index: divisionResult) + chars
        }
    }

    return chars
}

func getCharFromArr(index i:Int) -> String {
    if(i < alphabets.count){
        return alphabets[i]
    }else{
        print("wrong index")
        return ""
    }
}

for _ in 0...numFiles {
    fileName = getCharacter(counter: counter)+".png"
    print(fileName)
    counter += 1
}

fileName = getCharacter(counter: Double(numFiles))+".png"
print(fileName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can keep it numeric, just use the right option when sorting:

```
let arr = ["1.png", "19.png", "2.png", "10.png"]

let result = arr.sort {
    $0.compare($1, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending
}

// result: ["1.png", "2.png", "10.png", "19.png"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd really like to make them alphabetical, try this code to increment the names:

```
/// Increments a single `UInt32` scalar value
func incrementScalarValue(_ scalarValue: UInt32) -> String {
    return String(Character(UnicodeScalar(scalarValue + 1)))
}

/// Recursive function that increments a name
func incrementName(_ name: String) -> String {
    var previousName = name
    if let lastScalar = previousName.unicodeScalars.last {
        let lastChar = previousName.remove(at: previousName.index(before: previousName.endIndex))
        if lastChar == "z" {
            let newName = incrementName(previousName) + "a"
            return newName
        } else {
            let incrementedChar = incrementScalarValue(lastScalar.value)
            return previousName + incrementedChar
        }
    } else {
        return "a"
    }
}

var fileNames = ["a.png"]
for _ in 1...77 {
    // Strip off ".png" from the file name
    let previousFileName = fileNames.last!.components(separatedBy: ".png")[0]
    // Increment the name
    let incremented = incrementName(previousFileName)
    // Append it to the array with ".png" added again
    fileNames.append(incremented + ".png")
}

print(fileNames)
// Prints `["a.png", "b.png", "c.png", "d.png", "e.png", "f.png", "g.png", "h.png", "i.png", "j.png", "k.png", "l.png", "m.png", "n.png", "o.png", "p.png", "q.png", "r.png", "s.png", "t.png", "u.png", "v.png", "w.png", "x.png", "y.png", "z.png", "aa.png", "ab.png", "ac.png", "ad.png", "ae.png", "af.png", "ag.png", "ah.png", "ai.png", "aj.png", "ak.png", "al.png", "am.png", "an.png", "ao.png", "ap.png", "aq.png", "ar.png", "as.png", "at.png", "au.png", "av.png", "aw.png", "ax.png", "ay.png", "az.png", "ba.png", "bb.png", "bc.png", "bd.png", "be.png", "bf.png", "bg.png", "bh.png", "bi.png", "bj.png", "bk.png", "bl.png", "bm.png", "bn.png", "bo.png", "bp.png", "bq.png", "br.png", "bs.png", "bt.png", "bu.png", "bv.png", "bw.png", "bx.png", "by.png", "bz.png"]`
```

You will eventually end up with

> a.png
>   b.png
>   c.png
>   ...
>   z.png
>   aa.png
>   ab.png
>   ...
>   zz.png
>   aaa.png
>   aab.png
>   ...